# Is the Keras example for Autoencoders supposed to work?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I tried to implement the autoencoder from the keras website: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

I used the exact code from the page to get sort of a baseline for what the autoencoder should do. In the article, the autoencoder which has only 1 layer, produces a recognizable result but if i run it locally, the autoencoder produces only noise. Is the example supposed to work out of the box or are additional adaptions neccessary?

Additionally, the weights of the network does not seem to update correctly as the loss stays constant over training:

```
Epoch 47/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 0.6886 - val_loss: 0.6885

Epoch 48/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 0.6884 - val_loss: 0.6883

Epoch 49/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 11us/sample - loss: 0.6883 - val_loss: 0.6881

Epoch 50/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 12us/sample - loss: 0.6881 - val_loss: 0.6880
```

Comment: If you are making predictions on the MNIST dataset, you should get similar results

Comment: I copied the sample code into my project to see how it works and after running i get the results described in my post ..

Comment: I tried on my end and I got similar results to what you have, so there is indeed an issue. However, this autoencoder is very very simple and shouldn't be able to perform well. It would be interesting to understand why the results from Keras' website differ from that.

Comment: Ok at least i did not make some stupid mistake while copying as my python is a bit rusty. I will look for a contact and ask them directly then.